# Parsing a ISO8601 String to Date in Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting the next string from an API which claims

> All date formats are ISO8601.

I am trying with the next code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let updatedAtStr = "2016-06-05T16:56:57.019+01:00"
let updatedAt = dateFormatter.date(from: updatedAtStr)
```

Unfortunately resulting *updatedAt* is nil

Comment: Just change your `dateFormatter.dateFormat` to  `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"`

Comment: Inconveniently, I've found that Python's `Datetime.isoformat()` output does not produce what `ISO8601DateTimeFormatter()` considers to be valid. Maybe because the data source has no timezone information?? The easiest solution seems to be to explicitly set the format, as mentioned here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect, you need to take into account the milliseconds.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"

let updatedAtStr = "2016-06-05T16:56:57.019+01:00"
let updatedAt = dateFormatter.date(from: updatedAtStr) // "Jun 5, 2016, 4:56 PM"
```

Just to clarify, the addition of `.SSS` in the date format is what fixes the problem.

Comment: Also note, "In macOS 10.12 and later or iOS 10 and later, use the NSISO8601DateFormatter class when working with ISO 8601 date representations."

Comment: Altho ISO8601DateFormatter exists, I found it doesn't work as well as this answer. (Try 2021-04-05T15:47:22.000000Z which is, as far as I can tell a valid ISO8601 date, but doesn't work with ISO8601DateFormatter.date(from:)

Comment: On the other hand, 2021-04-06T12:57:28+00:00 which is also valid, works with ISO8601DateFormatter, but not with this answer. Why is this stuff so hard?!