# Swift ISO8601 format to Date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I have the following string: `20180207T124600Z`

How can I turn this into a Date object?

Here is my current code but it returns `nil`:

```
let dateString = "20180207T124600Z"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = .withFullTime
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString))
```

Comment: `formatOptions` is an NSOptionsSet so you can specify multiple options using an array. If you check the documentation you likely want `withFullTime` and `withFullDate`

Comment: With your current `dateFormatter` options, do `let date = Date.init() let str = dateFormatter.string(from:date), print("str:\(str)")`, you should see then that the formatOption is not correct, use the one given by @Oliver Atkinson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a ISO8601 String to Date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433852/parsing-a-iso8601-string-to-date-in-swift)

Comment: That date isn't in the ISO-8601 format. So it's not a big surprise that you can't parse it with `ISO8601DateFormatter`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify ISO8601 date formate to the NSDateFormatter to get Date:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)) //2018-02-07 12:46:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 25):

If you have a date such as:

```
let isoDate = "2018-12-26T13:48:05.000Z"
```

and you want to parse it into a Date, use:

```
let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
isoDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
isoDateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withDashSeparatorInDate,
    .withFractionalSeconds]

if let realDate = isoDateFormatter.date(from: isoDate) {
    print("Got it: \(realDate)")
}
```

The important thing is to provide all the options for each part of the data you have. In my case, the seconds are expressed as a fraction.

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify the format options for the `ISO8601DateFormatter` to match your requirements (year, month, day and time), here is an example below:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let dateString = "20180207T124600Z"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withYear,
    .withMonth,
    .withDay,
    .withTime
]

print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
print(dateFormatter.date(from: dateString))
```

Answer (score 4):

ISO8601DateFormatter should be something like

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

as long as your date string is in right format, it won't return nil.

as for `formatOptions`, it's Options for generating and parsing ISO 8601 date representations according Apple docs

**Swift 4**

in your example, it should be something like this:

```
let dateString = "2016-11-01T21:10:56Z"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

let dateFormatter2 = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.formatOptions = .withFullTime
print(dateFormatter2.string(from: date!))
```

Comment: that doesn't match his input string "20180207T124600Z"

Comment: yup, if the input string can't be changed, then @sid Mhatre 's answer is the best solution

Comment: you can specify the formatting options to match his input whilst still using the ISO8601Formatter https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867293/1755720

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to get date...

```
func isodateFromString(_ isoDate: String) -> Date? {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ"
    return formatter.date(from: isoDate)
}
```