# Parse ISO8601 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, date, iso8601

I am parsing `2020-06-09T18:11:26.904Z` and it returns this `09 Jun, 11:11 pm` it should be `06:11 pm`

I have tried this solution [Parsing a ISO8601 String to Date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433852/parsing-a-iso8601-string-to-date-in-swift) but it also works like the same.

Here's my code.

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
guard let date = df.date(from: dateTime) else {
    return nil
}

df.dateFormat = "dd MMM, hh:mm a"
df.amSymbol = "am"
df.pmSymbol = "pm"
let stringFromDate = df.string(from: date)
return stringFromDate
```

I know I could ask it on the mentioned link but due to the new user I couldn't add comment on that.

Comment: Use: ISO8601DateFormatter() to get all the logic for free.

Comment: It looks like you have problem just with time zone. Try to set the correct time zone like this `df.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`

Comment: where to set correct timezone?

Comment: Please check my updated comment above

Comment: You also can initizalize time zone with its identifier, just start typing `TimeZone(` and autocomplete will show you all options

Comment: @imike thanks it worked.

Comment: Hi Mir, searching for "ISO8601 Swift" yields 96 on this site alone. I've marked one of them as a duplicate. If you're still having trouble, you should ask about concretely what you're struggling with

Comment: please unAcceept the answer ... i need to delete it ...

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I tried that solution but that did not work for me that's why I ask a new question as I am new to the community I was not able to comment on that question.

Comment: @jawadAli You are free to go.

Comment: @MirMuhammadHadiAli You should mention that in a stackoverflow question. People appreciate seeing the background research/work you've done. You should ask concretely what didn't work when trying to follow the other solution

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Updated the question. Hope it is fine now!

Comment: @MirMuhammadHadiAli Much better! I think I know what's going on. For one, you should understand that `Date` represents an instant in time, with no timezone attached. Fundamentally, it's just a wrapper around a `Double`, which counts a number of seconds after the "reference date" (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001). What's probably happening here is that you didn't specify the `timezone` of the formatter you're using to print the date, so it defaults to your system's timezone (as stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1411406-timezone))

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica got your point thanks for explaining it well. I hope you can remove the rejection to my question now.

Comment: @MirMuhammadHadiAli Although I can't find a duplicate question for the "didn't set a timezone" mistake you made, so I'll answer here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the timezone of the output date, so it's defaulting to your systems' timezone rather than UTC (which is what you were expecting).